# How to dismiss transparent Android activity and tap through to a second activity showing underneath it

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have two activities, one which is transparent with a second activity showing underneath it. Is it possible to tap the transparent activity, dismiss it and have the tap carry through to the activity underneath?

Comment: _"Is it possible to tap the transparent activity, dismiss it and have the tap carry through to the activity underneath?"_ No, as long as the transparent `Activity` is in foreground.

Comment: Is there a way that I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean exactly by "carry through", but this is what you can do in Android.

Start Activity A. When starting Activity B, start as such:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A, B);
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_RESULT_CODE);
```

Then when you dismiss Activity B, aka call finish(), you need to make sure you send a result:

```
Intent goBackToActivityA = new Intent();
goBackToActivityA.putExtra(PUT_EXTRA_FOR_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_IN_A);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, goBackToActivityA);
finish();
```

And then when you get back to Activity A, you will need to capture that result and handle it:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == SOME_RESULT_CODE) {
           if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           // extract PUT_EXTRA_FOR_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_IN_A here
           // whatever the "carry through" is you can manage here
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: This would assume that both Activity A has implemented the overriden method onActivityResult. Suppose I wanted to apply this logic to all activities in my app, this would be a pain. In iOS, it is possible to handle the tap for the view B and then pass it to view A. This would allow an object in view A to be tapped while allowing us to perform some sort of action in view B. There must be a way to tap activity A, dismiss activity A, and then perform the tap on activity B.